# Draggable and Droppable function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Let's say I have some droppable div's on my left hand side titled zone 1 - 4.

```
<div id="zone1"></div>
<div id="zone2"></div>
<div id="zone3"></div>
<div id="zone4"></div>
```

And some draggable items on my right hand side

```
<div id="drag1">Apple</div>
<div id="drag2">Banana</div>
<div id="drag3">Kiwi</div>
<div id="drag4">Orange</div>
```

I know that I can set these up as draggable and droppable as follows:

```
for (var i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
   var x = "zone" + i;
   $(x).droppable();
}
  for (var i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
   var x = "drag" + i;
   $(x).draggable();
}
```

Now how would I go about triggering a function to start when a fruit is dropped in a zone that will give me both where it was dropped (zone1, zone2 etc.) as well as which fruit was dropped there. Ideally, I wouldn't want the fruit name, I would want an id associated with the fruit perhaps hidden in a hidden input tag or something?

Comment: Did you have any joy with any of the solutions? Make sure you mark a solution as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you do this instead of what you have.

```
<div id="zone1" class="droppable"></div>
<div id="zone2" class="droppable"></div>
<div id="zone3" class="droppable"></div>
<div id="zone4" class="droppable"></div>

<div id="drag1" class="draggable">Apple</div>
<div id="drag2" class="draggable">Banana</div>
<div id="drag3" class="draggable">Kiwi</div>
<div id="drag4" class="draggable">Orange</div>
```

Then for your script:

```
var fruit_id = '';
var dropbox_id = '';
$( '.draggable' ).draggable();
$( '.droppable' ).droppable({
               drop: function( event, ui ) {
            fruit_id = $(ui.draggable).attr('id');
                            dropbox_id = $( this ).attr('id');
                            /* DO SOMETHING HERE */
        }
});
/* Or do something here! */
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

An example from [this tutorial](http://www.elated.com/articles/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/)

```
$(init)

function init() {
  $('#makeMeDraggable').draggable();
  $('#makeMeDroppable').droppable( {
    drop: handleDropEvent
  } );
}

function handleDropEvent( event, ui ) {
  var draggable = ui.draggable;
  alert( 'The square with ID "' + draggable.attr('id') + '" was dropped onto me!' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop` event of the `droppable` interaction. In this event handler `$(this)` points to the droppable element where as ui.draggable points to the draggable element.

```
for (var i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
   var x = "zone" + i;
   $(x).droppable({
      drop: function(){
          //This will alert the id of container in which fruit is dropped
          alert($(this).attr('id'));

          //This will alert the id of fruit container which is dragged
          alert($(ui.draggable).attr('id'));
      }
   });
}
  for (var i=1;i<=4;i++)
{
   var x = "drag" + i;
   $(x).draggable();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this out. But I'm having a problem, my div's aren't being droppable. I check the class and there is no ui-droppable. In actuality I have it being called like this
var x = "#l" + currLay + "zone" + i;
where currLay and i are integers. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
.zones>div{ border:solid 1px gray; background-color:yellow; padding:20px;margin:5px;}
</style>

<div class="zones">
    <div id="zone1"></div>
    <div id="zone2"></div>
    <div id="zone3"></div>
    <div id="zone4"></div>
</div>


<div id="drag1" fruitid="1">Apple</div>
<div id="drag2" fruitid="2">Banana</div>
<div id="drag3" fruitid="3">Kiwi</div>
<div id="drag4" fruitid="4">Orange</div>

<script>

$("div[id*='zone']").droppable({
            accept: "div[id*='drag']",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                alert( ui.draggable.text() + " with fruitid = "+ ui.draggable.attr("fruitid")+" added to " + $(this).attr("id"));
                  $( "<div/>" ).text( ui.draggable.text()).appendTo( this );
            }
        })
$('div[id*="drag"]').draggable({helper: "clone"});

</script>
```

Comment: You can make your own attributes like fruitid??

Comment: that's why 'x' stands for in 'xhtml' :)

Comment: @MelihOKURSOY, that's invalid XHTML. if you specified a custom namespace and namespaced the attribute it would be valid. If it was HTML5 you could prefix `data-` on the attribute and it would be valid. The `data-` attribute is the better choice, as jQuery's `.data()` function will pull the `[data-]` attribute values.